# How to style EditorGUI field

Tags: unity, editors

You can style `EditorGUILayout` field with following code:

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);

EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedProperty, true);

EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
```

[image: EditorGUILayout with style]

But when you use it this way:

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);

EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, serializedProperty, true);

EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
```

This happens:

[image: EditorGUI with auto style]

With fixed height:

[image: Fixed height]

Comment: looks like the little squares are the background colour, I would try to stylize the contents of the array rather than the array itself. That way you have more control.

Comment: @user3797758 That is not a problem I am having, but thanks for suggestion. The squares can be edited via editing the texture.

Comment: I came across this problem as well. Haven't found a solution using `BeginVertical` but if the goal is to paint the background, I used `EditorGUI.DrawRect(position, new Color(0.19f, 0.19f, 0.19f))` instead

Comment: @PixelCakeGames now that I am looking at this question after so much time has passed, I see that it's quite a poor quality question and I didn't give any context in code to those images. But if you want to know an  answer to this - the problem basically lies in ways of structuring GUI. GUILayout works based on what already is in the inspector and uses other elements to determine its positions. While just GUI needs a specific `Rect` with position and size of the element. I used both here which is wrong, they don't work together. I might answer this question someday in the future.